# How could I deploy multiple maven artifacts to multiple nexus repositories including snapshot repositories without having to specify a profile?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

We have a gateway-client project that is part of a multi-module maven project.  The gateway-client pom.xml is configured to create two main artifacts: gateway-client.jar and gateway-services-client.jar and deploy them to two separate Nexus repositories: the Releases repo and the 3rd Party repo respectively.  This is done through a profile that is active by default:

```xml
<profile>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- default Profile -->
    <!-- This is the default profile which will run by default.  This profile -->
    <!-- produces two client artifacts: gateway-client and gateway-services-client -->
    <!-- for the releases and thirdparty repositories respectively. -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <id>default</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- default Profile Build plugins -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <!-- default Profile Maven deploy plugin -->
            <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-thirdparty-jar</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>${nexus.url}/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
                            <repositoryId>thirdparty</repositoryId>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gateway-services-client</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-release-jar</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases</url>
                            <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gateway-client</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The problem is that because this profile is active by default, if we try to run a `mvn deploy` and the version of the GAV coordinates is a -SNAPSHOT, the build unintentionally still tries to deploy to Nexus 3rd Party and Releases repos and fails because of course it won't accept -SNAPSHOT artifact versions.  To get around this, I setup a profile specifically for -SNAPSHOT versions which will only deploy to the Snapshot repository:

```xml
<profile>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- snapshot Profile -->
    <!-- Activating this profile will automatically deactivate the default profile. -->
    <!-- The purpose of this profile is to produce a a gateway-services-client and gateway-client -->
    <!-- snapshot artifacts and deploy them to the snapshots Nexus repository where they can -->
    <!-- act as the latest development dependencies for other projects -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <id>snapshot</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- snapshot profile Build plugins -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <!-- snapshot profile Maven deploy plugin -->
            <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-thirdparty-snapshot-jar</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>${nexus.url}/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                            <repositoryId>snapshots</repositoryId>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</file>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>gateway-services-client</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The problem with this is that you must specify the profile when executing the Maven command: `mvn deploy -P 'snapshot'`.  My question is what can I do so that all I have to do is run `mvn deploy` without specifying the snapshot profile and have the build automatically deploy to the snapshot repository or to the 3rd Party and Releases repositories all based on the presense of -SNAPSHOT in the version of the GAV coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that comes to my mind is using properties and adding three executions during deployment. The ugly thing is that in case of SNAPSHOT your artifact would be deployed twice to the same repository.

Here is what you could do:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>eval-repo</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>
                    if (project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")){
                    project.properties.repoId = "snapshots";
                    project.properties.repoUrl = "snapshots url";
                    project.properties.thirdPartyRepoId =   "snapshots";
                    project.properties.thirdPartyRepoUrl = "snapshots url";                             
                    }
                    else {
                    project.properties.repoId = "releases";
                    project.properties.repoUrl = "releases url";
                    project.properties.thirdPartyRepoId =   "thirdparty";
                    project.properties.thirdPartyRepoUrl = "thirdparty url";                                    
                    }
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then add three executions with the following configurations:

```
    <configuration>
        <artifactId>gateway-client</artifactId>
        <url>${repoUrl}</url>
        <repositoryId>${repoId}</repositoryId>
        ...

    <configuration>
        <artifactId>gateway-services-client</artifactId>
        <url>${repoUrl}</url>
        <repositoryId>${repoId}</repositoryId>
        ...

    <configuration>
        <artifactId>gateway-services-client</artifactId>
        <url>${thirdPartyRepoId}</url>
        <repositoryId>${thirdPartyRepoUrl}</repositoryId>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with profiles. From the maven doc:

> A profile can be triggered/activated in several ways:
>
> - Explicitly
> - Through Maven settings
> - Based on environment variables
> - OS settings
> - Present or missing files

So you can't do it the way you want it. However, we do this all the time. Our setup is we use the following in our super-pom

```
 <distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>deploymentRepo</id><!-- key in settings.xml -->
     <name>Releases</name>
     <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
     <url>${repos.release}</url>
     <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>
   <snapshotRepository>
     <id>deploymentRepo</id>
     <name>Snapshots</name>
     <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
     <url>${repos.snapshot}</url>
     <layout>default</layout>
   </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>
```

Note the id is the same because both repos use the same credential.

We are also using nexus where each repo is configured as snapshot or release and just with this, maven is capable of knowing that *-SNAPSHOT goes to the snapshot repo.

In other words, just give both options at the same time, don't put them in mutually exclusive profiles, and maven will know which way to send them. If it doesn't, try a repo manager

Comment: AFAIK you can only add one `<repository>` element under `<distributionManagement>`. If I understood correctly what he's trying to achieve your solution would neither solve the problem of needing to deploy releases of the same artifact to two different repositories nor to only deploy releases (i.e. no snapshots) of one of the artifacts to the 3rd party repository.

Comment: @Clauds you hit on the flaw of this answer.  I wanted to do something like what Hilikus is saying but I couldn't figure out a way to both 1)deploy to multiple Nexus repos and 2)automatically deploy to both releases and 3rd party Nexus repos if there is no snapshot in the version or deploy to just the snapshot Nexus repo if there is a snapshot in the version

Comment: @Sheparzo i didn't understand that you wanted to deploy non-snapshots to 2 repos and snapshots to 1 (a different) repo. 
The only problem really is deploying to two repos. My solution works for the normal case of deploying snapshots to 1 repo and non-snapshots to another (different) repo.
Anyway, the best practice in maven is 99% of times, 1 pom = 1 artifact

[See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298744/maven-generating-several-artifacts-with-a-same-pom-file).
if you fix that you won't have this problem

Comment: @Hilikus Good point separating the artifacts. This way he could use the standard deploy approach for release/snapshot and would only need one additional deploy to publish non-snapshot to the the 3rd party repo.