# Splitting a list of test methods into two JARs using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have read some Q/A about how to generate two JARs using a single Maven `pom.xml` file, but I am having troubles applying what I read to my specific case since I am a beginner with Maven.

I have a package used for running some tests in my CI. The structure of the Maven project is as follow:

```
pom.xml
src
|_  main
    |_  java
        |_ model
        |  |_ Something.java
        |_ suites
           |_ TestSuiteA.java
           |_ TestSuiteB.java
           |_ TestSuiteC.java
```

Right now I am generating a single JAR file which is destined to be used in the CI to run those tests. What I would like to do is creating two JARs:

- A JAR for `TestSuiteA` and `TestSuiteB`
- A JAR for `TestSuiteC`, as those tests need to be ran in a separate part of the CI

Right now, the `pom.xml` looks like that:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.testpackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>testpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>fatjar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <package-name>net.myorg.uitests.suites</package-name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I tried using excludes and includes directive to have two JARs including different files:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.testpackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>testpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- First JAR -->
                <execution>
                    <id>build-first</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>fatjar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <!-- Exclude TestSuiteC -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/suites/TestSuiteC</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <package-name>net.antidot.bo.uitests.suites</package-name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Second JAR -->
                <execution>
                    <id>build-second</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>fatjar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>client</classifier>
                        <!-- Exclude everything except TestSuiteC -->
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/suites/TestSuite*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/suites/TestSuiteC</include>
                        </includes>
                        <package-name>net.antidot.bo.uitests.suites</package-name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I am unsure about what to do next. I tried running `mvn package` but it only produced one JAR file.
Is this the correct approach? If yes, what step should I take next?

Comment: Splitting project into project with multiple submodules would be the preferred solution. Generating many artifacts from single pom.xml 
isn't recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298744/maven-generating-several-artifacts-with-a-same-pom-file .

Comment: If you really need to separate classes make separate projects (modules) of it...best and simplest solution...

Comment: if its the test-classes you need to split / package there is also the source plugin that allows creating a test-jar in addition to the jar based on the files in src/main: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html - there is an includes parameter, so adding two executions of the plugin and configure it differently to get multiple jars out. The maven convention is one pom one artifact. So the above suggestion splitting the files into sub-modules may be closer to the maven concepts. Are the tests so big? You could package them all in one jar and just execute some.